# How can I get Intellisense function completions working for external libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-completion

I was coding a new project to majorly update it to include cross compatibly however my IntelliSense went kinda werid it worked sometimes but other times not, here is an example:

```
"Text". # it works here
1. # it works here

import tkinter
tkinter.Tk(). # it doesn't work
```

I didn't install any extensions at least in my memory,
I tried uninstalling extensions, I checked the settings, and its still not fixed.

Do you know how I can fix this? It really is annoying for me to not have IntelliSense.

Also

Comment: @PranavHosangadi nope.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this problem. You can hover your mouse over `tkinter` to see if you can obtain relevant information about the package.

[image]

If you didn't get this information and run the file got **ModuleNotFound** error, you have to check whether you chose the correct python interpreter (**"Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter"**).

If you can run the file successfully, this may be caused by pylance not finding the path of package. You can add the following codes to your settings:

```
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "Path/to/your/package"
  ]
```

BTW, restarting VsCode may also be a solution.

Comment: I restarted VSCode multiple times and hovering over the module works.

Comment: @LawrenceWilliams This package [works well on my vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJHS4.png). Have you set Pylance as your python language server? Add `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` to your `settings.json`.